# Swift - Directions to Selected Annotation from Current Location in Maps

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit, mklocalsearch

My app currently has a local search which adds annotations for the search results. I want to set it up where when you select the annotation and click the call out button, it will open in the Maps application with directions to the annotation from the current device location. I'm having a few problems with this.

First of all, my call out button on the annotation does not appear. Secondly, I don't think I am detecting the selected annotation correctly.

Here is my code for the search and selected annotation:

```
func performSearch() {

    matchingItems.removeAll()
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText.text
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response:
        MKLocalSearchResponse!,
        error: NSError!) in

        if error != nil {
            println("Error occured in search: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response.mapItems.count == 0 {
            println("No matches found")
        } else {
            println("Matches found")

            for item in response.mapItems as! [MKMapItem] {
                println("Name = \(item.name)")
                println("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")

                self.matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
                println("Matching items = \(self.matchingItems.count)")

                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                var coordinates = annotation.coordinate
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

            }
        }
    })
}



func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!,
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {

        if self.mapView.selectedAnnotations?.count > 0 {

            if let selectedLoc = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations[0] as? MKAnnotation {
                println("Annotation has been selected")
                let currentLoc = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()
                let mapItems = NSArray(objects: selectedLoc, currentLoc)
                let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
                MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([selectedLoc, currentLoc], launchOptions: launchOptions)
            }
        }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For the first issue:**

A callout button needs to be set explicitly in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method (default red pins don't have one).  Here's a simple example of one possible implementation:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.pinColor = .Purple

        //next line sets a button for the right side of the callout...
        pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton
    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```

**For the second issue:**

First, in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, the annotation is directly accessible using `view.annotation` so using the `selectedAnnotations` array in there is unnecessary.

Next, `openMapsWithItems` expects an array of `MKMapItem` objects but in the array you are passing (`[selectedLoc, currentLoc]`), `selectedLoc` is *not* an `MKMapItem` -- it is just some object that implements `MKAnnotation`.

Running this code will result in a crash with this error:

> -[MKPointAnnotation dictionaryRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

when the Maps app tries to use `selectedLoc` as if it was an `MKMapItem`.

Instead, you need to create an `MKMapItem` from the `selectedLoc` annotation.  This can be done by first creating an `MKPlacemark` from the annotation using `MKPlacemark(coordinate:addressDictionary:)` and then creating an `MKMapItem` from the placemark using `MKMapItem(placemark:)`.

Example:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!,
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {

        let selectedLoc = view.annotation

        println("Annotation '\(selectedLoc.title!)' has been selected")

        let currentLocMapItem = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()

        let selectedPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: selectedLoc.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
        let selectedMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPlacemark)

        let mapItems = [selectedMapItem, currentLocMapItem]

        let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]

        MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems(mapItems, launchOptions:launchOptions)
}
```

Comment: Somehow I downvoted this answer without even knowing (someone was playing with my phone). I apologize for that. Now I can't undo. If you want you can make an edit so I can revert this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! My last question is... How can I assign the view to the created annotations in the `performSearch()`? After adding the code and running, the annotation view is still the default red pin.

Comment: You don't directly call the `viewForAnnotation` method because it is a delegate method.  The map view will call it automatically.  But your map view's `delegate` outlet in the storyboard must be connected to the view controller.  Or, in code, in `viewDidLoad`, do `mapView.delegate = self`.  If the map view's delegate is not set, the delegate methods won't get called even if implemented and the map view will then do its default actions.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much for the help! I'm still in a learning process, sorry for bothering you with so many questions :D